# UTF-8 char in path used by groovy in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, utf-8

I need to copy a file, using a groovy script in Jenkins (pipeline). This file has the character ü in it, which results in the file not being found. I've tried renaming the file to a standard u, and it works. However, this is not an option, I need the ü. Any suggestions how to solve this?

Edit: I'm using Windows 7, using the batch command xcopy.

Edit2: The command being issued is:

```
bat "xcopy \"${files[i].path}\" \"${path}\""
```

Where files[i].path is the file name containing the ü character, and path is the complete path where to put the file.

Comment: please edit your question and add some details: what is the destination operation system? what command do you use to copy a file?

Comment: and command in jenkins - `bat` ? how do you call it? what are the parameters?